# Recovering Excel file

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have auto recovery on my Excel program and I save my work several times a day.  Tonight, I turned on the computer and it had shut down down for some apparent reason.  When I pulled up my Excel program it only showed one auto recovery file form 8am this morning even though I worked/added onto my Excel sheet for several hours this afternoon.

Is there any way to recover my work I did this afternoon?

Comment: several hours? you should learn how to press Ctrl+S from time to time

Answer (score 1):

Possible, but it depends on what version you have and how the AutoRecovery options were set up.

1. In Excel 2010 the location can be found by selecting `File > Options > Save tab` it is listed under `Save workbooks`.
2. In 2007 its `Office Button > Options > Save tab` it is listed under `Save workbooks`.
3. In 2003 its `Options > Tools > Auto recover file location'.

Here is more information about [AutoRecovery](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/289273).

Comment: I am using Excel 2007 on windows vista, accidentally I over save my excel document after major changes and now want to restore it on previous version but I found nothing in the save workbooks path.