# How do I recover a previous version of an Excel file which was overwritten?

Tags: windows-vista, microsoft-excel-2007, file-recovery

Does anyone know of a way to recover a previous version of an MS Excel (2007) file in Windows Vista Home Premium version, which I've accidentally wrote over?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Recovering Excel file](http://superuser.com/q/486677)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vista supports the [Volume Snapshot Service (VSS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_Copy) that allows for the recovery of files even if you haven't made a backup. If you have the Business, Enterprise, or Ultimate version of Vista, simply right-click on the current version of the Excel file, choose "Properties" then select the "Previous Versions" tab. Then select the prior version of the file and restore it.

From the [Windows Vista, 7 and Server 2008](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_Copy#Windows_Vista.2C_7_and_Server_2008) section of the Wikipedia [VSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_Copy) article:

> Shadow copies are created automatically once per day, or manually when
>   triggered by the backup utility or installer applications which create
>   a restore point. The "Previous Versions" feature is available in the
>   Business, Enterprise, and Ultimate editions of Windows Vista and
>   in all Windows 7 editions. The Home Editions of Vista lack the
>   "Previous Versions" feature, even though the Volume Snapshot Service
>   is included and running. Using third-party tools it is still possible
>   to restore previous versions of files on the local volume.

If you don't have one of those versions of Vista, try [ShadowExplorer](http://www.shadowexplorer.com/), which is a free tool, though you might consider a donation to the author of the tool if it allows you to recover a needed file you couldn't otherwise recover, that supports recovery from snapshots.

> ShadowExplorer allows you to browse the Shadow Copies created by the
>   Windows Vista / 7 / 8 Volume Shadow Copy Service. It's especially
>   thought for users of the home editions, who don't have access to the
>   shadow copies by default, but it's also useful for users of the other
>   editions.
>
> **Shadow Copy**
>  From time to time, Windows Vista / 7 / 8 creates point-in-time copies of your files. This allows you to retrieve older
>   versions from files you accidentally deleted or altered. This service
>   is turned on by default on all versions of Windows Vista/7, but
>   Microsoft grants access to these copies only in Ultimate, Business,
>   and Enterprise editions. This is where ShadowExplorer comes into play.

Comment: thanks for that.. it is really such a very useful software.